# Vue/Vuetify Testing ~ Cannot read property 'componentInstance' of null

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I am testing a Vue / Vuetify Application.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/buys-fran/vue-form-test

I have one test suite with two tests.

- When I run one test only (either one) the test passes.
- When I run both tests it breaks and I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentInstance' of null"

I am testing a component with a v-form ([Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#form)).

- When I use `<v-form :value="valid">` the test passes.
- When I use `<v-form v-model="valid">` it breaks and I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentInstance' of null"

I don't know where to start looking - any help will be greatly appreciated.

Context

1. Testing with [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/)
2. Using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html)

Comment: I did open a vuetify issue if you would like to contribute over there: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6625

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Were you ever able to find a solution to this?